# How do I make this text field editable and not editable with a button. Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

how do I make the "title" text field editable when the edit button is pressed.

preferably the edit button should be at the right hand side of the app bar next to the done button.

[image]

Here is my code, ive removed most of the code for the other fields to save character limit for this post but kept the code for the "title" text field.

Thank You!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class viewLossEvent extends StatefulWidget {
  String code,
      title,
      orgUnit,
      riskOfficer,
      natureOfEvent,
      islamicBusiness,
      shariahRelated,
      incidentType,
      operationalRiskLossType,
      countryOfEvent,
      stateOfEvent,
      districtOfEvent,
      modusOperandi,
      factOfIncident,
  //Status Approval and Validation
      status,
      incidentOwner,
      rejectionComment,
      ormdRec,
      reasonNotValid,
  //Incident Categorization
      busline1,
      busline2,
      busline3,
      proServ,
      delChannel,
      causCat1,
      causCat2,
      causCat3,
      causCatOth,
      eventcat1,
      eventcat2,
      eventcat3,
      boundOthRisk,
      payInst,
      cardBrand,
      payChan,
      cardType,
      busAct,
      accType,
      depRisk,
      riskAss,
      riskRate,
  //Fraud Related Information
      possfraud,
      iADRD,
      iADF,
      iADC,
  //Incident Dates
      discDate,
      discTime,
      occDate,
      occTime,
      resDate,
      resTime,
      subBNMDate,
      dateIncRep,
      recDate,
      closeDate,
  //Incident Loss Data
      grossLoss,
      recoveryAmmount,
      netLoss,
      recoveryEC,
      contingentLia;


  viewLossEvent(
      {this.code,
      this.title,
      this.orgUnit,
      this.riskOfficer,
      this.natureOfEvent,
      this.islamicBusiness,
      this.shariahRelated,
      this.incidentType,
      this.operationalRiskLossType,
      this.countryOfEvent,
      this.stateOfEvent,
      this.districtOfEvent,
      this.modusOperandi,
      this.factOfIncident,
      this.status,
      this.incidentOwner,
      this.rejectionComment,
      this.ormdRec,
      this.reasonNotValid,
      this.busline1,
      this.busline2,
      this.busline3,
      this.proServ,
      this.delChannel,
      this.causCat1,
      this.causCat2,
      this.causCat3,
        this.causCatOth,
      this.eventcat1,
      this.eventcat2,
      this.eventcat3,
      this.boundOthRisk,
      this.payInst,
      this.cardBrand,
      this.payChan,
      this.cardType,
      this.busAct,
      this.accType,
      this.depRisk,
      this.riskAss,
      this.riskRate,
      this.possfraud,
      this.iADRD,
      this.iADF,
      this.iADC,
      this.discDate,
      this.discTime,
      this.occDate,
      this.occTime,
      this.resDate,
      this.resTime,
      this.subBNMDate,
      this.dateIncRep,
      this.recDate,
      this.closeDate,
      this.grossLoss,
      this.recoveryAmmount,
      this.netLoss,
      this.recoveryEC,
      this.contingentLia});

  @override
  State<viewLossEvent> createState() => _viewLossEventState();
}

class _viewLossEventState extends State<viewLossEvent> {

  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void _navigateBottomBar(int index){
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  bool isReadOnly = true;

  void _edit(){
    setState(() {
      isReadOnly = !isReadOnly;
    });
  }

  List<Widget> _pages = [];

  void initState() {

    super.initState();
    _pages = [
      Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              //Main Info
              ListTileTheme(
                tileColor: Colors.grey,
                child: ExpansionTile(
                  title: Text(
                      'Main Info',
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(textStyle: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 20,))
                  ),
                  children: [
                    //Fields
                    ListTileTheme(
                      tileColor: Colors.white,
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text('Code : ${widget.code}',
                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(textStyle: const TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                            fontSize: 20,
                          ),),),
                      ),
                    ),
                    ListTileTheme(
                      tileColor: Colors.white,
                      child: ListTile(
                        leading: Text(
                          'Title : ',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                          ),
                        ),
                        title: TextField(
                          readOnly: isReadOnly,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black),
                            hintText: '${widget.title}',
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),     
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              //Shariah Details
              ListTileTheme(
                tileColor: Colors.grey,
                child: ExpansionTile(
                  title: Text(
                      'LE Shariah',
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(textStyle: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 20,))
                  ),
                  children: [
                    //Fields

                  ],),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              //Shariah Details
              ListTileTheme(
                tileColor: Colors.grey,
                child: ExpansionTile(
                  title: Text(
                      'LE Attachment',
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(textStyle: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 20,))
                  ),
                  children: [
                    //Fields

                  ],),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              //Shariah Details
              ListTileTheme(
                tileColor: Colors.grey,
                child: ExpansionTile(
                  title: Text(
                      'LE Action',
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(textStyle: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 20,))
                  ),
                  children: [
                    //Fields

                  ],),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              //Shariah Details
              ListTileTheme(
                tileColor: Colors.grey,
                child: ExpansionTile(
                  title: Text(
                      'Compliance Incident',
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(textStyle: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 20,))
                  ),
                  children: [
                    //Fields

                  ],),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ];
  }




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF002d62),
        title: Text('${widget.code}',
            style: GoogleFonts.sora(
              textStyle: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 25,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              ),
            )),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),

            onPressed: _edit,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: _pages[_selectedIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          onTap: _navigateBottomBar,
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'General'),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.balance), label: 'LE Shariah'),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.attachment), label: 'LE Attachment'),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.call_to_action), label: 'LE Action'),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person_pin_circle), label: 'Compliance Incident'),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instaed of using `enabled:` 
use  `readOnly: ,`

```
bool isReadOnly = true;
```

this is how your textfield looks

```
TextField(
readOnly: isReadOnly,
 decoration: InputDecoration(
 hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black),
 hintText: '${widget.title}',
 border: InputBorder.none,
),
```

on your edit button

```
onTap:(){
setState(() {
   isReadOnly = !isReadOnly;
});
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I know its supposed to work but im not sure why it isnt. Theres no error, its just not doing anything

Comment: can you show me your latest code

Comment: yup ive just updated the post with the latest code. Thanks

Comment: you have given the pages(the widgets) in a list may be thats why it did't get updated in setState call . you need to use any of the statemanagement packages in flutter to achive this

Comment: use getX or Provider or any other statemanagement

Answer (score 1):

You can set
enabled: isEditable in TextField

When You click on the Edit button set the value of isEditable

```
setState(() {
   isEditable=!isEditable;
});
```